# Centered array with intertext

Tags: amsmath, arrays

I would like to use `\intertext` inside an array, so I'm using

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
...
\begin{gather*}
    \begin{array}{lll}
        u & v & w
\intertext{Blah, blah, blah} 
        x & y & z
\intertext{Blah, blah, blah}
        a & b & c
    \end{array}
\end{gather*}
```

This results in the maths being left-aligned. How can I align the maths in the center?

Comment: Please make your code compilable; e.g., do state which document class is in use and which packages are being loaded. And please exlain why the `array` environment is defined to have 6 columns even though only 3 appear to be in actual use.

Comment: I've added `amsmath` and switched 6 columns for 3. (My original source uses six columns, but three columns suffice to demonstrate the problem.)

Comment: I think it is pure luck that this does not give you an error. `\intertext` was never meant to be used inside `array`. Exactly why are you using this combination?

Comment: @daleif, because it looks like it has the potential to do what I want...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you replace the `gather*` environment with an `alignat*` environment -- and *not* use an `array` environment.

Use the following code to get three left-aligned columns, separated from each other by `2\arraycolsep`. Why `2\arraycolsep`, you might ask? Because that's the amount of intercolumn whitespace that's inserted between two columns of an `array` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
        &uvw &\hspace*{2\arraycolsep}& abc &\hspace*{2\arraycolsep}& def \\
\intertext{Blah, blah, blah}
        &x && y && z \\
\intertext{Blah, blah, blah}
        &\alpha && \beta && \gamma
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```